# Compile multiple less file and copyto a folder as multiple css file using gruntjs

Tags: less, gruntjs

I'm trying to output multiple  less files under less folders to build/css folder

here is the code i'm having where i have to specify individual files and its working fine

```
less: {
        build: {
            options: {
                yuicompress: true,
                paths: ['public/less']
            },
            files: {
                '.build/css/app1.css': 'public/less/app1.less',
                '.build/css/app2.css': 'public/less/app2.less'
            }
        }
    }
```

I try to make it more generic and tried this but not working

```
less: {
        build: {
            options: {
                yuicompress: true,
                paths: ['public/less']
            },
            files: {
                  expand: true,
                  cwd: 'public/css',
                  src: '*.less',
                  dest: '.build/css',
                  ext: '*.css'
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my grunt versions

```
grunt-cli v0.1.9
grunt v0.4.2
```

Is there anything missing to any config need to be added?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is typo in `cwd` and `src` should be an array instead of a string and `ext` has been changed as well, also `dest` is incorrect.

```
files: {
    expand: true,
    cwd: 'public/less',
    src: '[**/*.less]',
    dest: 'build/css',
    ext: '.css'
}
```

Comment: This is not working
what does  src: '[**/*.less]' means?

Comment: I'm getting warning like this.    
  `Running "less:build" (less) task    
    Warning: Object true has no method 'indexOf' Use --force to continue.`

Comment: I wrapped like files : [{....}] and the warning was gone and new  css folder is created but no  css files created

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me, my build folder name is ".build"

```
files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'public/less/',
                src: '**/*.less',
                dest: '.build/css',
                ext: '.css'
}]
```